# angular 2 Insert new table items to top of table

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that adds TODO's to a table, and I wanted to know how you would go about adding the new TODO's to the top of the table rather than the bottom. I have seen a few answers on SO showing how to achieve this in JS but I wanted to know how to do it with Typescript. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You can order the list by datetime of submission DESC. If you post the code you have now we can help you

Comment: You can also just use unshift to add the new element to the beginning of your array/list.

Comment: What do you mean by typescript. use splice function only in typescript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use unshift to add the item to the begining of your array.

**Example** http://plnkr.co/edit/7FC8IUvdR3wPevrd48yt?p=preview

```
 <div>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newTodo" placeholder="Add New Todo"/>
  <button type="button" (click)="addTodo()">Add</button>
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let todo of todos">{{todo}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>


export class App {
  newTodo: string;
  todos: Array<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.newTodo = "";  
    this.todos = ["Grocery Shopping", "Banking"];
  }

  addTodo() {
    this.todos.unshift(this.newTodo);
    this.newTodo = "";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**`splice`** function in **`Typescript`** can be used to do what you want.

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/B5l1fCOvItkt45cJMBKO?p=preview**

```
<input type="text" #newItem>
<button (click)="add(newItem.value)">Add</button>

<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
         <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

```
export class App {

  items=[{name:"Computer"},{name:"Laptop"}];
  add(newItem){
    this.items.splice(0,0,{name:newItem});
  }
}
```